# Rancher plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rancher

Anyone used rancher plugin for jenkins to deploy containers to rancher?

I am using this plugin [Rancher Plugin For Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Rancher+Plugin#app-switcher)

To being with, I deployed a hello-world container in Rancher by adding a host and then new container from UI.

Next I tried to automate through Jenkins. Followed all the instructions as per plugin page.
I was confused with the **"Service Name"** field.
[image]

**Question:**
**What should be the service name .**

My stacks has All / User /Infrastructure options only.Below image is of my rancher-server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Service name is the Service name inside the stack. You need to mention the stack name also.

I'm using Jenkins in deploying into Rancher too. But I'm using Rancher Cli because it is much better and mature in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

We also were looking for something suitable but my colleagues figured out that there ain't a really cool solution. Then we decided to use Jenkinsfiles, so we took the steps and implemented a maven plugin for rancher deployments. It can be found here : https://github.com/crowdcode-de/rancher-maven-plugin - one can easily integrate it into the Jenkinsfile by providing some basic configuration parameters and running the goal rancher:stack-deploy from the Jenkinsfile. Only restriction is, that maven is available.